# Factorise $f(a, b, c)=a^3+b^3+c^3$, if $a^2+b^2=c^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

A while ago, in one of my country's respected mathematical journals, this problem came up:

> If $a^2+b^2=c^2,$ factorise the following expression over the integers: $f(a, b, c)= a^3+b^3+c^3.$

I was baffled as I could not find a way around the problem. It reminded of a certain identity of Euler's but this was different and something seemed pretty off about the question itself. Anyway, $f$ is symmetric and invariant under all permutations of $a, b, c$ and homogeneous of $\deg 3$, meaning that $f(ta, tb, tc)=t^3f(a, b, c) \forall t \in \mathbb{Z}$, so the odd part was that $a^2+b^2=c^2$ is not symmetric for all those permutations aforementioned. Why would a distinction between $a, b, c$ be made in the requirement in the first place? Furthermore, the authors never responded with any answer whatsoever. I would very much appreciate if you could help untangle this problem and either solve it or prove definitively that it is impossible (which I think is much more likely). I believe I have tried every single possible way to factorise it but I have not been able to create any common factors between all three.

Comment: If you meant "over the integers" instead of "over the reals" (seeing as you tagged the question with the **[number-theory]** and **[elementary-number-theory]** tags), then since $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, then without loss of generality we may assume $a = m^2 - n^2$, $b = 2mn$, $c = m^2 + n^2$.  (I forgot if there is an additional requirement on $m$ and $n$.)  This is the usual parametrization for *Pythagorean triples*.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor+completely+%28m%5E2+-+n%5E2%29%5E3+%2B+%282mn%29%5E3+%2B+%28m%5E2+%2B+n%5E2%29%5E3) gives the factorization $2m^2 (m + n)^2 (m^2 - 2mn + 3n^2)$.  This may be rewritten as $(a + c)(b + c)(2c - b - a)$.

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris Indeed, I meant over the integers. I have considered such parametrization and have proceeded to this particular factorization but I was not able to further progress expressing it only in terms of $a, b, $ or $c$.

Comment: Do check out my answer below, @LorentzianMcDonalds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, then $(a, b, c)$ is a *Pythagorean triple*.

Without loss of generality, we may assume that
$$a = m^2 - n^2, b = 2mn, c = m^2 + n^2.$$
(I forgot if there is an extra condition on $m$ and $n$.)

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor+completely+%28m%5E2+-+n%5E2%29%5E3+%2B+%282mn%29%5E3+%2B+%28m%5E2+%2B+n%5E2%29%5E3) then gives the factorization
$$(m^2 - n^2)^3 + (2mn)^3 + (m^2 + n^2)^3 = 2m^2 (m + n)^2  (m^2 - 2mn + 3n^2).$$

This may be finally rewritten in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$ as
$$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = (a + c)(b + c)(2c - b - a).$$

Comment: Brilliant! I am not sure how I missed this! P.S. There are no extra conditions on $m, n$, they can be random integers.

Comment: Note: The "WLOG" isn't true yet, because it's just for Primitive Pythagorean triples. What you actually have is $ a = (m^2-n^2)k, b = 2mnk, c = (m^2+n^2)k$. Luckily, this doesn't affect the rest of your solution since the $k^3$ factors out.

Comment: @CalvinLin: Yes, that is exactly what I meant when I said that I may have forgotten an extra condition on $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that

$$ 0 = (a^2 + b^2 - c^2 ) ( a+b+c) = a^3+b^3+c^3 - (a+c)(b+c)(2c-a-b).$$

Hence, we have $ a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = (a+c)(b+c)(2c-a-b)$.

---

Notes

- Assuming there's a nice solution (esp if it's an "olympiad problem"), then there are limited things we can try.
- We need to use the condition that $ a^2 + b^2 - c^2 = 0 $, which we likely have to multiply by a linear factor. $(a + b \pm c) $ makes the most sense.
- I first chose $ a + b - c $ because it gives us $ a^3+b^3+ c^3$, but then I couldn't factorize the rest of the terms (without further using $c^2=a^2+b^2$).
- I then went with $a+b+c$, which led to the above.
- If those didn't work, I would have tried $ a \pm b + c $ (but that's somewhat unlikely since $a, b$ should be symmetric).
- The other thing I tried was $ a^3+b^3 + c^3 - 3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca)$ but that didn't seem to help. Note the $(a+b+c)$ term here, so there might be a way to force through the algebraic manipulation.

Comment: +1 especially for showing the working process to get there — really nice!